# How can I return both a string and an integer value from a method?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am having a hard time figuring out how to return my function with a "%" sign.

Here is what I have:

```
def calculate(string):
    A = string.count("A")
    D = string.count("D")
    x = A + D
    answer = (x / len(string)) * 100
    return int(answer)
```

I want it to return the final answer, but with a percentage sign next to it, like '65%' for example

I tried these:

```
return int(answer) + "%"
return int(answer) and "%"
```

but none of those really worked and it gave me an error.

Comment: `return str(answer) + '%'` or `return "{}%".format(answer)` or `return "%d%%" % (answer,)`

Comment: [Read the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/). It will tell you how to convert numbers to strings. Or how to format string with numeric values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a single returned value: you can't

The problem is that `int(answer)` is a number and `'%'` is a string, so you cant combine these in a return value - unless you convert both to the same data type.

Try converting both values to a string:

```
return "{}%".format(int(answer))
```

Comment: @Gin. Glad to see you've made some progress with your homework since yesterday :)

Answer (score 0):

You could go totally overboard and define your own integer type that displays itself with a percent symbol:

```
class pint(int):
    def __str__(self):
        return super().__str__() + '%'
    __repr__ = __str__
```

You can now make the return value of your function be `pint(answer)` and reap the benefits of having your number actually be a number while always printing as a percentage.

I don't really recommend this approach for your trivial case, but it could have its uses.